# Can I cast cloudkill inside of a building while I'm outside of it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, vision-and-light, targeting

If I cast a spell like [*cloudkill*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/cloudkill) that says:

> You create a 20-foot radius sphere of poisonous, yellow-green fog centered on a point you choose within range.

Am I able to cast it inside of a building while I'm outside of it? Assuming the building has no windows and I've never seen the inside of it before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need a [clear path to the target](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#AClearPathtotheTarget), so what you propose wouldn't work.

From page 204 of the PHB:

> To target something, you must have a clear path to it, so it can't be behind total cover. If you place an area of effect at a point that you can't see and an obstruction. such as a wall, is between you and that point, the point of origin comes into being on the near side of that obstruction.

Unless there is a hole or something in the building that you could cast the spell through then you can't simply cast a spell within a building because the walls, windows or what-have-you would obstruct the spell's path.